# worldpay payment gateway error using SNI - change the callback URL to use HTTP instead of HTTPS

Tags: magento-1.9, payment-methods, https, worldpay

Worldpay is my payment gateway and we use SNI certificate on the server.

However, WorldPay is not compatible over SNI at the moment. The recommended solution by the tech team over there is to change the callback URL to use HTTP instead of HTTPS.

1) Can someone guide me how to do this on Magento because I am totally confused?

2) Also what kind of security implications could this cause? and should his page be hidden from search engines etc?

i think the change needs to be made in the htaccess file, but i'm not sure. 
Just change the one page to be sent over http instead of https

Comment: i think the change needs to be made in the htaccess file, but i'm not sure. Just change the one page to be rested over http instead of https

Answer (score 0):

you will have to use a dedicated ip address for your shop, to properly work with any https payment gateways that dont support SNI.

changing payment links to HTTP is a bad idea.